# In pandas dataframe (with a set in every cell) when adding new element to a set in a specific cell, element is added to all cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set

I have a DataFrame filled with sets consisting of element "O" that looks like this:

```
     1    2    3    4
4  {O}  {O}  {O}  {O}
3  {O}  {O}  {O}  {O}
2  {O}  {O}  {O}  {O}
1  {O}  {O}  {O}  {O}
```

I want to add elements from the list `['A11\n', '\n', 'B21\n', '\n', 'P31\n']` in a way that the letter is added to the set in the following cell coordinates. For example B goes to the cell with the index = 1 and column = 2.

I used the following code (in this case `lines` is equal to `['A11\n', '\n', 'B21\n', '\n', 'P31\n']`):

```
for line in lines:   
    if line[0] == "A":
        width = int(line[1])
        height = int(line[2])
        board.at[height, width].add("A")
```

Instead of getting the the following DataFrame:

```
     1     2    3    4
4  {O}    {O}  {O}  {O}
3  {O}    {O}  {O}  {O}
2  {O}    {O}  {O}  {O}
1  {A,O}  {O}  {O}  {O}
```

I get:

```
        1       2       3       4
4  {A, O}  {A, O}  {A, O}  {A, O}
3  {A, O}  {A, O}  {A, O}  {A, O}
2  {A, O}  {A, O}  {A, O}  {A, O}
1  {A, O}  {A, O}  {A, O}  {A, O}
```

I don't understand where i went wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you would want to perform an update of your cell with an "=" assignment.  Following is a sample code snippet for your consideration.

```
import pandas as pd

board = pd.DataFrame([['{O}', '{O}', '{O}', '{O}'], ['{O}', '{O}', '{O}', '{O}'], ['{O}', '{O}', '{O}', '{O}'], ['{O}', '{O}', '{O}', '{O}']], columns=['1', '2', '3', '4'])
lines = pd.DataFrame(['A11', 'B21', 'C31', 'D41', 'E12', 'F22', 'G32', 'H42','I13', 'J23', 'K33', 'L43','M14', 'N24', 'O34', 'P44',], columns=['line'])

print('Before: ')
print(board)

for x in lines.index:
    width = int(lines.loc[x][0][1])
    height = int(lines.loc[x][0][2]) - 1
    if width == 1:
        board.loc[height].at['1'] = board.loc[height].at['1'][0] + lines.loc[x][0][0] + board.loc[height].at['1'][1] + board.loc[height].at['1'][2]
    elif width == 2:
        board.loc[height].at['2'] = board.loc[height].at['2'][0] + lines.loc[x][0][0] + board.loc[height].at['2'][1] + board.loc[height].at['2'][2]
    elif width == 3:
        board.loc[height].at['3'] = board.loc[height].at['3'][0] + lines.loc[x][0][0] + board.loc[height].at['3'][1] + board.loc[height].at['3'][2]
    else:
        board.loc[height].at['4'] = board.loc[height].at['4'][0] + lines.loc[x][0][0] + board.loc[height].at['4'][1] + board.loc[height].at['4'][2]
        
board = board.sort_index(ascending=False)        
        
print('After: ')
print(board)
```

Note all of the substring operations happening in the sample code.  The width test isn't elegant, but it gets the job done for the sample.  You can probably come up with a nicer algorithm there.

Following was the result of this test program.

```
    Before: 
     1    2    3    4
0  {O}  {O}  {O}  {O}
1  {O}  {O}  {O}  {O}
2  {O}  {O}  {O}  {O}
3  {O}  {O}  {O}  {O}
After: 
      1     2     3     4
3  {MO}  {NO}  {OO}  {PO}
2  {IO}  {JO}  {KO}  {LO}
1  {EO}  {FO}  {GO}  {HO}
0  {AO}  {BO}  {CO}  {DO}
```

Anyway, play around with that and see if it lets you progress.

Regards.